# Import Dates into Mongodb using MDBC and Powershell

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I have been using the mongodb cmdlets module on github that allows for easy importing to mongodb from powershell:

https://github.com/nightroman/Mdbc/blob/master/README.md

The import of the data is working as I would expect, with the exception of the date times that I am importing. They are coming accross as a string after the import finishes.

Below is my code, as you will see I am using powershell's get-date cmdlet to convert the date to a 24 hour dateTime format that is excepted when I manually change the data type in mongodb compass.

```
$creation_time         =  gci -recurse -File | get-itemproperty | select -ExpandProperty CreationTime   | get-date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff'
$last_access_time      =  gci -recurse -File | get-itemproperty | select -ExpandProperty LastAccessTime | get-date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff'
$last_write_time       =  gci -recurse -File | get-itemproperty | select -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime  | get-date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff'
$file_extension        =  gci -recurse -File | get-itemproperty | select -ExpandProperty Extension
$file_base_name        =  gci -recurse -File | get-itemproperty | select -ExpandProperty BaseName
$file_path             =  gci -recurse -File | get-itemproperty | select -ExpandProperty DirectoryName 


$adsObjects       = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
for($i=0; $i -lt $creation_time.Length; $i++){
    $object = New-Object System.Object
    $object | Add-Member -type NoteProperty –Name _id        –Value    $file_base_name[$i]
    $object | Add-Member -type NoteProperty –Name Extension  –Value    $file_extension[$i]
    $object | Add-Member -type NoteProperty –Name Directory  –Value    $file_path[$i]
    $object | Add-Member -type NoteProperty –Name CreateDate –Value    $creation_time[$i]
    $object | Add-Member -type NoteProperty –Name Accesstime –Value    $last_write_time[$i]
    $object | Add-Member -type NoteProperty –Name Writetime  –Value    $last_access_time[$i]
    $adsObjects.Add($object)
}

# Load the module
Import-Module Mdbc

# Connect the new collection test.test
Connect-Mdbc . test test -NewCollection

# add the objects to the collection
$adsObjects | Add-MdbcData

# Get all data as custom objects and show them in a table
Get-MdbcData -As PS | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String
```

Does anyone know how I can ensure that the values of the dates I am sending over can be set to be a date format? This is an important thing for the application I am working on as there are date range queries I need to incorporate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to ensure that the member is `DateTime` is to cast it in your `For` loop

Example:

```
$creation_time = ("01/01/2018","02/02/2018") #For testing
$adsObjects       = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
for($i=0; $i -lt $creation_time.Length; $i++){
        $dateTime = Get-Date($creation_time[$i]) #Casting to DateTime
        $object = New-Object System.Object
        $object | Add-Member -type NoteProperty –Name _id        –Value    $file_base_name[$i]
        $object | Add-Member -type NoteProperty –Name Extension  –Value    $file_extension[$i]
        $object | Add-Member -type NoteProperty –Name Directory  –Value    $file_path[$i]
        $object | Add-Member -type NoteProperty –Name CreateDate –Value    $dateTime
        $object | Add-Member -type NoteProperty –Name Accesstime –Value    $last_write_time[$i]
        $object | Add-Member -type NoteProperty –Name Writetime  –Value    $last_access_time[$i]
        $adsObjects.Add($object)
    }
```

We can confirm this with a simple `Foreach` loop:

```
foreach($member in $adsObjects)
{
    Write-Host $member.CreateDate
    Write-Host ($member.CreateDate).GetType()
}
```

Output:

```
1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM 
System.DateTime 
2/2/2018 12:00:00 AM 
System.DateTime
```